# Perl - using sed or tail to remove first line of a file inline and return 1st line to a var

Tags: perl, sed, tail

This is very new to me but, I am slowly picking it up.

I need to open a file, return first line to a var to do stuff then delete first line from file after stuff is successful.

In mt script, here is what prints all but the first line to screen.

```
$file = 'test.txt';

system "tail -n+2 /home/username/public_html/adir/$file";
```

Now I did some poking around here and found:

```
system "sed -i '1d' home/username/public_html/adir/$file";
```

Which is supposed to remove the first line of the file inline. (I did not try)

That would be perfect if I could also return the first line to a $variable to do stuff.

If stuff fails, I could add the line back into the file.

I know I could do this with a bunch of FILE < and > with arrays but, seems a bit much.

The file is small, less than 100 lines of 6 characters each.

Am I totally clueless as to pursuing sed or tail for this?

How do I return the removed line as $line using these system calls?

Thanks for the learning experience.

Comment: do you want to use perl or do you want a shell script using sed and tail ? please do not use perl just to call system.

Comment: I don't really know. I tried it, it returned a result. The script is a server based Perl script that updates a users info to a mysql table from another. It will be triggered by a cron. The $file is a list of user id's that need updated. The id is the key that triggers a database sync for that user/row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the kind of thing that [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) is perfect for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my $file = 'test.txt';

tie my @array, 'Tie::File', $file or die "Count not tie file: $file: $!";

my $line = $array[0];

if (do_something_successfully()) {
  shift @array;
}
```

Comment: Okay, after I shift off the first in array, I assume I use a open(FILE, ">, $file"); and write the modded @array in the successful if?

Comment: Like:  if (do_something_successfully()) {
shift @array;
open FILE, q[>], $filetoopen;
foreach (@array){
print FILE $_;
close(FILE);
}

Comment: Nope. The joy of Tie::File is that the array _is_ the file. If you change the array (by, for example, `shift`ing its first line) then you change the file. My code is almost complete. You just need to write the `do_something_successfully` function. Maybe you should read the documentation I linked to :-)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I had to install Tie::File but, man, that is awesome!!! I am not worthy...

Comment: Slightly worried that you had to install Tie::File. What version of Perl are you using? It has been a part of the Perl core distribution since 5.8.0 in in July 2002. You should really consider upgrading to a newer version!

Comment: I discovered it just verified install was up to date. But, now I have to figure out how to put: if (do_something_successfully()) {
 in a different sub so, I need pass the @array. stuff(\@array); possibly?

Comment: Got it all going, thanks for your help. I used -s and -z to verify whether to process file or not as well. THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the idea to use `system()` for tasks that `perl` is brilliant.

How about?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, q[<], $ARGV[0] or die $!; 

## Read from the filehandle in scalar context, so it will read only
## first line.
my $first_line = <$fh>;

# do stuff with first line...

## And if stuff was successful, read left lines (all but the first one) and
## print them elsewhere. 
while ( <$fh> ) { 
    print;
}
```

Comment: That will delete the first line of the file? Where does that actually happen? That is cool. Sorry, really new to this and want to learn the mechanics. Something in the open statement removes the first line, then, at the end it re writes / 'print' the file with the first line removed?

Comment: @Jim_Bo: I've updated the answer to add explanation in comments, but yes, the program reads from filehandle in scalar context, so only the first line, and following reads will be from second line to the end of file.

Comment: Excellent. I tried this but, the file was not edited. The displayed results were perfect. So, in the while would I print $fh [what]?

Comment: This doesn't alter the original file. It prints the new file contents to STDOUT. You'd need to redirect that output to a new file. And the rename the new file to the old name. Using Tie::File avoids all of that.

Comment: @DaveCross: Thank you. Redirect is an option, and edit in-place another one. Never used `Tie::File`, but reading your answer looks promising.